# Android. Setting default value for invalid json field

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit2, converters

I am using retrofit and json converter. I create POJO which contains some fields. One of these fields should be int, but if the server sends something else instead of int, I need to write the default value in this field, for example 2. Now if the server sends something other than int, I get an exception (json malformed exception) in my request, since in the POJO the field is declared as int. Is it possible to write a default value in this field if the server sends something other than int.

Comment: This is possible with most json libraries with custom type converters. Make a converter that tries to parse the value as an int and fallback on a default value if that fails.

Answer (score 0):

in case the server is sending you null you can use Int to store the value, otherwise the parsing won´t be successful; on the other hand if you require a different value other than null as a default you can override your set or get method; set to if is null set the value to zero or get if the value is null return 0.

Hope it helps to debug your problem, if the server is sending you multiple values like strings, booleans, etc. You should discuss which value is the one that you need.